# Where can I find template SSIS package that would create file ( Excel, txt, csv) from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, templates, ssis

I have lots of requirements to generate and deliver files with different extensions, such as:  .xlsx, .txt, .csv

I am not good at c#, but I am assuming there is a SSIS package with Script Task where you just have to change variable names like `Extension`, `StoredProcedureName` etc. And it will dynamically create file of whatever extension and insert output of that SP into the file.

Does anybody encounter SSIS package template that would do something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Use the command line tools for SQL Sever (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).  I recommend using SQLCMD.exe.  You can put into a bat file and run the bat.  A Power Shell had build in methods that call SQLCMD.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how an SSIS dataflow works, what you are looking for won't exist. The metadata (data about the types, number of columns, etc) is tightly bound to the design-time experience of an SSIS package. Attempting to change it at run time will result in a validation error (VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA).

Even if you could get changing metadata to work, the output becomes the next problem. You can change the file name or target table name or any of a host of other things at run-time. What you cannot change though, is the target itself. I can't have a package modify itself to emit to Flat File and in the next run, flip a flag and now we generate an Excel file.

If you have coding skills, you could create the package on the fly based on metadata and then run itself but that's not a *fun*  task due to the mix of COM and .NET objects.

If it were me, I would look at a something like [Biml](http://bimlscript.com/). Use the metadata you have to build a package that addresses all the possible permutations (Source query A to Excel, Flat File, CSV, etc). Once you have the pattern down, you then make a package for all possible source queries. Then, you've reduced your problem to orchestration - which package do I run?